# Sorting 2D data in a list

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

I have a `Point` class

```
class Point
{
    double X, Y;
}
```

And defined a list of `Point`:

```
List<Point> list;
```

How do I sort the list such that it is first sorted by `X`, then by `Y`?

So meaning my data, when sorted looks like this:

```
{1,1}
{1,2}
{1,3}
{2,2}
{2,5}
{2,7}
```

where it is `X` first, followed by `Y`.

I have tried to use is:

```
list.OrderBy(a=>a.X);
```

But this may not ensure that the `Y` are ordered as well. Is there a LINQ like expression that can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Orderby...ThenBy`:

```
list.OrderBy(p => p.X).ThenBy(p => p.Y);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort it "in place" (without creating a new collection), you can:

```
list.Sort((p, q) =>
{
    int res = p.X.CompareTo(q.X);

    if (res == 0)
    {
        res = p.Y.CompareTo(q.Y);

        // If you had a Z:
        //if (res == 0)
        //{
        //    res = p.Z.CompareTo(q.Z);
        //}
    }

    return res;
});
```

The code inside the `{ ... }` is a good "template" on how to build a comparer function that has to work on multiple fields.